# Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add action in a plugin in a file which is included to the base php plugin file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

Then I am requiring the file in the main plugin file:

```
require_once  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'api/index.php';
```

, but I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in
```

This code works fine, if it is in the main plugin file, but if I put it in another file it doesn't. 
I have followed some answers to similar questions to include `wp-load`, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: what other files are you putting it in? as you have pointed out, the fatal error means add_action is not defined, which does mean that wordpress core is not included and bootstrapped before PHP attempts to parse the file. that is definitely the issue. is there a reason you don't want to register your action in the main plugin file?

Comment: There is a possibility that you have directly added the `add_action` function in your included class which is not technically wrong but cause the `add_action` function to be called before **WordPress is ready** and causes the error. You should call the include event in a function in a function and call that function at the very end of the plugin's main file.

Answer (score 0):

Following this code, I think you might solve your issue.

```
// You must define the wp_ajax_my_action callback 
function my_action( $my_action_callback ) { 
    // Write your action
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
```

If you want to get more info, please refer to http://hookr.io/actions/wp_ajax_my_action/

Good luck!